# sql server 2008 partitioning column

Tags: sql-server

[According to microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933141%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) An Identity column cannot be a partitioning column canadate.

*The partitioning column cannot be an identity, default or timestamp column.*

They do not clarify why that is nor has my google foo turned up a reason.

I have a theory, can SqlServer not automatically insert the row into the correct shard based on the identity field if it is the partitioned column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference is for **SQL Server 2000 and partitioned views.**

SQL Server 2008 allows `Identity` fields as the partitioning column in a **partitioned table.**

[See this link, excerpt below:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802.aspx)

> All data types are valid for use as partitioning columns, except text,
>   ntext, image, xml, timestamp, varchar(max), nvarchar(max),
>   varbinary(max), alias data types, or CLR user-defined data types.